# Obfuscate the SharedPreferences XML file through an update of an already published app without breaking it

Tags: java, android, xml, sharedpreferences

The app in context was my first app, and I was quite naive to store some sensitive info (ads related) using SharedPrefences. Is there a way to obfuscate the XML file without breaking the app?

The app has already been published, and is used by a lot of users.

Answer (score 0):

You can publish a new version, where you should update the key with sensitive data - read it, obfuscate\hash\encrypt it, and write it back.

For example, you can embed a key into your code and simply XOR the value on it. Or you can use any more secure cryptographic algorithm\scheme you like.

Comment: I could do that, but I'd be losing 1000s of users.

Comment: Implement a reversible obfuscate\encrypt, to be able to use this value in your app, put keep away "bad guys". But this protects from stupid bad guys only, as encrypt key will be embedded into the app.